# Grouping duplicates

Tags: haskell, grouping

Haskell gurus. Care to show me some more haskellian ways to perform this task that isn't restricted by my limited knowledge of haskell and FP in general?

```
groupDups [] = []
groupDups list@(x:xs) = groupDups' x list
  where groupDups' _ [] = []
        groupDups' x list = let (m,r) = partition (x ==) list
                            in m : groupDups r

> groupDups [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1]
[[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could `sort` the list, then `group` it:

```
> import Data.List
> (group . sort) [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1]
[[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2],[3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4]]
```

Comment: Cheers, that is much faster, looks like I was over thinking things again. However, now I need to implement a Ord instance for my custom data type.

Comment: @nipuL, that, or you could use `sortBy` instead of sort.  Then you'll just need `Eq` for `group`.

Comment: `sortBy` still needs a function that returns an `Ordering` given two keys.

Comment: @nipuL: you can't just `derive` it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid introducing an `Ord` constraint in the type you can use this:

```
import Data.List

groupDups []     = []
groupDups (x:xs) = (x : group) : groupDups xs' where
  (group,xs') = partition (==x) xs
```

It's correspondingly slower than `(group . sort)` and groups are ordered by first occurrence in the original list:

```
*Main> groupDups [1,3,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,4,3,2,1,4,3,2,1]
[[1,1,1,1],[3,3,3,3,3],[2,2,2,2],[4,4,4,4]]
```

You might be able to improve complexity slightly by making a helper function that accumulates into a parameter list, ask if you're interested in the details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something weird to do this.

```
groupDups ls = 
   map (\(h:­t) -> t) $ foldl­ (\s e -> map (\(h:­t) -> if h == e then (e:h:­t) else (h:t)­) s)   (nub [[x] | x <- ls])­ ls
```

Answer (score 0):

This function requires only `Eq`

```
groupDups xs = foldl insert [] xs
  where insert [] x = [[x]]
        insert (ys@(y:_):yss) x | x == y    = (x:ys):yss
                                | otherwise = ys:(insert yss x)
```